# How to disable the parent window control in C# web api

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-web-api

I am using a web api which takes XML as in body content, but Now i want to send Json in  body content.

But when i have tried sending json in body it is giving me parent window control error.

Any Suggestion will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Nitesh, to easily help you, kindly share a code snippet or snapshot of the code you are trying to execute.

Alternatively, from the abstract point of view, I suggest that you add "Content-Type" header key with a value of "application/json" to specify to the API server that the content is of a JSON format.

For more information about Content Type, I recommend reading the article about content-types https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Thank you